# Is it possible to create a RSS feed containing all blog entries?

Tags: rss, export

More specifically
I have a blog at riduidel.wordpress.com for which I would like to create that feed, for it to be later consumed in a site backup solution called autoblog, which can create a site copy by simply reading a RSS feed.
So is there such a tool available for wordpress.com sites (directly or not), or should I do a backup of my blog database then write a script generating that stream ?

Comment: wordpress.com questions are off topic, but you should be able to increase the number of feed items under Settings/Reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an [`add_feed()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_feed) function.  You pass it a function via the second callback parameter.  So something like this should work:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse102646_all_items_feed' );
function wpse102646_all_items_feed() {
    add_feed( 'allposts', 'wpse102646_get_all_items' );
}
function wpse102646_get_all_items() {
    $args = array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
    );
    $posts = get_posts( $args );
    $feed = '';
    global $post;
    foreach( $posts as $post ) {
        $feed .= get_the_title();
        $feed .= get_the_content();
    }
    return $feed;
}
```

*This code is untested.*

Also, I'm not entirely sure if `return $feed;` is what's required by `add_feed()`, or if you should instead `echo( $feed );`.  I suspect the former.

Additionally, any time you change your `add_feed()` code, you'll need to flush the permalinks.  The recommended way is to go to **Settings » Permalinks** and **Save** your existing permalink structure.

#### Reference

Codex:

- [`add_feed()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_feed)

Comment: Whoops, I didn't notice this was for wordpress.com.